# sklearn PCA producing numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, pca, svd

I wanted to run a pca on a matrix, but only got a numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError.
I attached the matrix and my code.

Get the matrix here: http://workupload.com/file/YvSVhGJA

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
matrix = np.load("matrix.npy")
transformed = PCA(n_components=3).fit_transform(matrix)
```

Here is the full stack trace, but I think you can reproduce it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 242, in fit_transform
    U, S, V = self._fit(X)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 275, in _fit
    U, S, V = linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py", line 109, in svd
    raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge")
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

Any help is appreciated.

PS:

```
np.__version__
'1.9.2'

sklearn.__version__
'0.15.2'
```

PPS: I am running Linux

Comment: I'm looking into it. This is not exactly an answer to your question but you can use RandomizedPCA as an alternative, I am not getting any error with it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my mac.

Comment: @cel The error comes from the lapack routine. You may have a different version that does a better job at computing the SVD.

Comment: @user3914041, possible, but hard to believe. I also ran the code with `anaconda`, so I did not compile `numpy`/`scipy` myself. Why should the `lapack` implementation shipped with `anaconda` have a better algorithm for `osx` ?

Comment: Anaconda accelerate: numpy 1.9.2,  sklearn 15.2. Cannot reproduce this error (ubuntu 64 bit(

Comment: @cel I am not familiar at all with LAPack routines and potential variations with the OS. I just traced down the exception that I could reproduce and it seems to be coming from LAPack. I'm on ubuntu 64 bit with the free anaconda version.

Comment: The accelerate version uses an intel LAPACK routine ... I do not know much about it, but I would either try R or compile numpy from scratch and use ATLAS+LAPACK

Answer (score 0):

It works on macs, which I guess doesn't help you much.
Try `X[:,:100]` then :1000 ?

There are [LAPACK tests for SVD](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawn41/node72.html); they look daunting.
A "tell me all about my LAPACK installation" command would be useful,
but I don't see that offhand.

```
from __future__ import division
import platform
import sys
import numpy as np
from numpy.distutils.system_info import get_info


np.set_printoptions( threshold=100, edgeitems=10, linewidth=80,
        formatter = dict( float = lambda x: "%.2g" % x ))  # float arrays %.2g

def versions():
    print "versions: numpy %s  python %s " % (
        np.__version__, sys.version.split()[0] )
    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        print "mac %s" % platform.mac_ver()[0]
    else:
        print platform.platform( terse=1 )  # ?
    for info in "blas_opt lapack_opt " .split():
        print "%s: %s" % (info, get_info( info, 0 ))
    print ""

versions()

#...............................................................................
X = np.load( "matrix.npy" )
print "X:", X.shape, np.percentile( X, q=[0,25,50,75,100] )

U, sing, Vt = np.linalg.svd( X, full_matrices=False )

print "np.linalg.svd: X %s -> U %s  sing %s  Vt %s" % (
    X.shape, U.shape, sing.shape, Vt.shape )
print "svd sing:", sing
```

---

```
versions: numpy 1.9.2  python 2.7.6 
mac 10.8.3
blas_opt: {'extra_link_args': ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate'], 'extra_compile_args': ['-msse3', '-DAPPLE_ACCELERATE_SGEMV_PATCH', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers'], 'define_macros': [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]}
lapack_opt: {'extra_link_args': ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate'], 'extra_compile_args': ['-msse3', '-DAPPLE_ACCELERATE_SGEMV_PATCH'], 'define_macros': [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]}

X: (384, 5000) [-4.4e+02 -20 -0.27 17 4.5e+02]
np.linalg.svd: X (384, 5000) -> U (384, 384)  sing (384,)  Vt (384, 5000)
svd sing: [5e+04 2.3e+04 2.1e+04 1.3e+04 1.2e+04 1.1e+04 1.1e+04 4.3e+03 3.3e+03 1.8e+03
 ..., 0.00014 0.00014 0.00013 0.00013 0.00011 5.3e-12 5.3e-12 5.1e-16 1.3e-16
 3.3e-17]
```